# How to update mongodb within two collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following TSQL query. How to update the same in Mongo Db.

First finding count of product based on the vendor and then update the vendor table count based on the number of products available in the product table.

```
Update Vendor
set Vcnt= p.cnt
from (select VendorId,count(*) cnt from Product
group by VendorId) p where Vendor.id=p.VendorId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate to group the count by `VendorId`. Then iterate the aggregate result by [forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) to update the `Vendor` collection.

Sample code:

```
db.Product.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$VendorId",
      "cnt": {
        "$sum": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(function(result){
    db.Vendor.update({
        _id : result._id
    }, {
        $set: {
            "Vcnt" : result.cnt
        }
    })
})
```